# Java MySQL create a column to join multiple rows of another table's column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Java MySQL create a column to join multiple rows of another table's column:

In other words I would like to understand if it is possible to have MySQL Java object (e.g. class A) that contains a list of references to istances of another object (e.g. class B).

Is ths possible? Which annotation should I use? (What I want to achieve by accessing to a field of an istance of class A to retrieve a list of references of istances of class B, the number of this is variable..).

I am using MySQL with Hibernate and SpringTool source (with Roo).

Many thanks!

Comment: Would [this](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-1.html) and [this](http://josian.wordpress.com/2006/09/09/hibernate-annotations-bidirectional-one-to-many/) help. also look at hibernate [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate please try via the `@OneToMany` annotation. Working with collections is explained in this section:

http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#entity-mapping-association-collections

As you wrote, you are using Spring Roo. So you just have to type

```
field set ...
```

Refer to http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html - Section A.12.8. (sorry, no HTML Anchor)